# Does Flow support the unique annotation from Doctrine?

Tags: flow-framework

Is something like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#errorpath) supported by Flow?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"host", "port"},
 *     errorPath="port",
 *     message="This port is already in use on that host."
 * )
 */
class Service
{
```

I need to validate that one title isn't used twice for one user.

**Edit**: Added model validator to check for uniqueness, but now it's checked in *all* actions: loading, updated etc.

**Edit 2**: "Solved" by checking in validator if object is new (not yet persisted). Still problem when updating already existent entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UniqueEntityValidator and only annotate the validator in the actions where you need to check the uniqueness.
http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/ValidatorReference.html#uniqueentityvalidator

Alternatively, you could maybe use ValidationGroups to only validate with your existing model validator in the places you want it to happen.
http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Validation.html?highlight=validationgroups#advanced-feature-partial-validation